# Modifying a class in a collection with undo

Tags: c#, collections, undo

This is not so much a question as to how to do something, but rather how I can implement something better or think about the problem differently.

I have a winforms application that allows the user to select multiple rows in a grid. These rows represent accounts and when the user selects the accounts and hits a button, a boolean property on the objects will change to whatever the selected value is regardless of it's existing state. However, if a validation method fails, a message is sent to the user and the boolean property needs to be set back to it's original state.

```
public void ModifyAccounts(List<DemoAccount> accts, bool updateIsSpecial)
{
    // Dictionary that will hold the account ID along with the booleans original state
    Dictionary<int, bool> originalState = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
    foreach(var acct in accts)
    {
        // Add the current state to the dictionary
        originalState.Add(acct.Id, acct.IsSpecial);

        acct.IsSpecial = updateIsSpecial;
    }

    // Send the list to another method that loops through each account and checks
    // for specific validation rules. Returns a collection of tuples. The tuple
    // contains the account for item1 and a bool validated flag for item2
    var valAccounts = ValidateAccounts(accts);

    var failedAccounts = from obj in valAccounts
                         where !acct.Item2
                         select new
                                  {
                                      account = obj.Item1,
                                      isValid = obj.Item2
                                  };

    if (failedAccounts.Count() > 0)
    {
        // Alert the user with custom msg box method that the accounts failed
        // Do Custom Method

        // Reset the values of the failed accounts to their previous state. 
        // It is possible that some accounts passed validation and were saved,
        // only the failed accounts should be reset. 
        foreach (var obj in failedAccounts)
        {
            bool originalFlagState = false;
            originalFlagStates.TryGetValue(obj.account.Id, out originalFlagState);
            var origAccount = accts.Where(x => x.Id == obj.account.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            origAccount.IsSpecial = originalFlagState;

        }
    }
}
```

I hope this isn't too confusing. I only have ~3 years of dev experience which is not a lot. However, I feel it's enough to understand when working on something that if it feels like there is a better way then I am probably not doing it correctly or efficiently. Modifying the account flag changes the object in the accounts list. Obviously adding the object to a new list will just create a reference to that object. So I can't do something like holding 2 collections one for modification and the other for original state. I also can't do a deep copy because the account class is not marked serializable. I cannot change this because of the type of object.

Thanks to anyone who can provide some advice or insight!

Comment: Can you validate before you change state? Anything that fails validation would remain untouched.

Comment: The validation takes in a list of my accounts with the change to see if the change is acceptable. Many changes can be made to an account so this method just loops through the account and checks all properties and throws an invalid flag when something fails. So when modifying the account, the initial unchanged data is essentially already validated. When I send the list to the validation method, i have to set the flag to what the user changed, this now sets any other collection containing that class.

Comment: I would personally find a way to pre-validate the data. You're letting bad data in, and that's bad (even when you only keep it for a moment). If you have multiple threads, you could easily end up with data corruption issues, and when maintaining the code, you'll have a greater chance of breaking something.

Comment: That's what I am trying to find the best way to do.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you want to validate after changing, and not beforehand.
But if you really have to validate and use undo afterwards there is a design pattern which supports this behavior

Have a look at the command pattern. Here is a code project link that describes how to implement it
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8303/Using-the-Command-pattern-for-undo-functionality

In your particular case I would iterate through the command stack and undo all commands which are used on failed accounts

It could look something like this

```cs
    foreach (var obj in failedAccounts)
         foreach ICommand command in commandStack
              If(command.element.Equals(obj))
                   command.undo;
```

command.element should contain the element you want to change with your command.

if you dont want two foreach u could use System.Linq operations